# Evil thoughts and waswasa

Tags: waswasa, evil-thoughts

I m a 24 years old girl and i have been getting very nasty imagination of prophet and allah since 10 yrs and evil thoughts. Sometimes i thought of talking to my family about the same in detail but i could not since i thought they are gonna scold me for what i say. I m so scared and afraid of allah that how i m going to face him. I pray salah 5 times but i m not able to get rid of that thing . M i destined for hell .what would happen to me in grave. M i so unlucky muslim or i can say human who is been suffering this and on top of that now a days i m suffering from a weired feelings i keep thinking about death i m so scrared that something is going to happen to me i m not able to sleep my body gets numb . My heart beats so fast and i get choking sensation ,cold sweat . I m not able to hear something negative. If i hear about death or sudden death of someone i get so scared and same condition as i described above. I feel like i also have to die . Please help me with these problems .

Comment: I recommend reading https://data2.dawateislami.net/Data/Books/Download/en/pdf/2016/559-1.pdf it covers many tricks of Shaitan and duas to protect you from his waswas. You could also try reciting these guards daily: https://www.dawateislami.net/bookslibrary/602/page/178

Answer (score -1):

You may consult with a doctor for your over thinking. And my personal opinion is start reading Quran with proper understanding and knowledge, think about every ayat , get lesson and relate to your everyday activities and ebadat.